# Django form validation does not validate image

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I need validation Image field (requared) in form, but is not work. I do not get validation error in template.

Image Form

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Image
        fields = ['title', 'image']
        name = forms.CharField(label='Title', max_length=100)
        image = forms.CharField(label='Image', max_length=100)

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
        if not title:
            return forms.ValidationError("title is requared")
        else:
            return title

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")
        if not image:
            raise forms.ValidationError("No image!")
        else:
            return image
```

view.py

```
if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=True)
        instance.save()
        return ImagesListView(request)
    else:
        return render(request, 'images/create.html', {'form': form})
```

Tenplate

```
  <form action="{% url 'images:create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table border="0">
                {{ form }}
            </table>
            <input class="btn bk-bs-btn-primary" type="submit" value="Загрузить изображение">
        </form>
```

Comment: show more code from your view. where you create form. Bye the way you don't need to validate if field is empty, because you define it in model without `blank=True` attribute, django will validate it for you.

Comment: ``form = ImageForm(); return render(request, 'images/create.html', {'form': form})

Comment: i don't see where you give posted data to your form, you need to define it `form = ImageForm(request.POST if request.POST else None)`

Comment: I change model to    image = models.ImageField(blank=False,null=False) and now it work